# How to Display First Word as Post Title only on Homepage in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need a solution to limit or display only **first word** of post title only on **homepage** in wordpress blog.

Example of a post: **Holiday Wordpress Theme Free Download**

Now, i want to display only **Holiday** word as post title only on **homepage** of a website. But the title should be complete on all other pages. Same like that to be applied on all post titles on homepage.

I have tried this code but it does not work

giving idea

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_75691_trim_words' );

function wpse_75691_trim_words( $title )
{
    // limit to ten words
    return wp_trim_words( $title, 10, '' );
}
```

OR

something like that

```
<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 5 ); ?>
```

I need a code to put in funcation.php to do the job. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `is_home()` function to determine whether or not the filter callback is being executed on the home page. Something like the below should work:

```php
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_75691_trim_words' );

function wpse_75691_trim_words( $title )
{
    // Limit the title to exactly one word only on the home page.
    if (is_home()) {
        return wp_trim_words( $title, 1, '' );
    }
    // Otherwise return the full title.
    return $title; 
}
```

Comment: Szabo, the code is not working, i tried it but not working for me, here is my site: https://copybloggerthemes.com click on any post title and check by inspect element, it has full post title, i used css if you see it as first word,

Comment: @bradly Where did you put the above code? Is the function called? (You can test using `echo` or `var_dump` or `die` or ... from within the functions body.)

Comment: @zolib Szabo i put the above code in function.php file at the bottom. Please mention how to use var_dump or die also share with echo the complete code. Thanks bundles

Comment: Szabo, i tried the above code its working now, but the problem is that, it apply on all title where the title tag used on my website it effect all the titles tag, i want to apply the above code only to h3 title tag, I hope you will modify it to add the h3 along with title..thanks